# Colab cannot find an installed a package

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory, apt, fenics

I'm trying to install a package called `fenics` in Google Colab.

I tried both:

```
!pip install fenics

>> fenics in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (2019.1.0)
```

and

```
!apt-get install fenics
```

Then a simple `import fenics` raises `ModuleNotFoundError`. Restarting the runtime doesn't solve the problem. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [instruction](https://fenicsproject.org/download/#crayon-5d4d0e594dbd0969054727)

```
!apt-get install software-properties-common
!add-apt-repository ppa:fenics-packages/fenics
!apt-get update
!apt-get install --no-install-recommends fenics
```

Then you can `import fenics`. Here's the [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1l0ACK2qBTfSHGv8SUPBgRVWYBlmWUYLQ) I tested.

Comment: Thanks Korakot. Just a doubt, why doesn't plain `pip install` work?

Comment: @Mstaino I don't know either. I have tried both methods, only apt-get works.

Comment: @Tarifazo `pip install` only works well for simple python packages.  fenics (dolfin) is no simple package, it has a long chain of numerical library dependencies and requires a C++ compiler for JIT compiling.   `pip install` does not work smoothly with python packages that build C binary extensions, requiring use of a C compiler and installed library dependencies.  These binary dependencies are managed by package managers such as apt.